# Blue Tinge for White Paint

Tags: organic-chemistry, reagents

I am trying to make an aqueous white paint with Mica and TiO2 as mainstay that gives a slight tinge of blue when it dries but should remain white while in solution.

So far I have tried optical brighteners but they havent been successful. What can I add in my paint for this?

Comment: But that would be expensive + paint will appear blue? I need to keep the paint looking white while it is in liquid state. Blue tinge only when it is dry.

Comment: Mica does not dissolve in water to yield a solution.  Neither rutile, nor anatase (both $\ce{TiO2}$) enter an aqueous solution either.  Perhaps, finely ground, you may get them stabilized in an emulsion (like, e.g., white tooth paste).  Dyes (soluble color agents) and pigments (color agents not soluble in water) of *blue* color you find in nature and which resist extended exposure to sun light are rare (e.g., lapis lazuli from Afghanistan).

Comment: Buttonwood pointed out to *lapis lazuli* in the comments, but I want give an interesting perspective. There is a very beautiful blie pigment used in South Asia as for a  post-laundry washing. It is literally dirt cheap and but pretty stable as a dye. It is an inorganic dye used to make white look bluish white. "Ultramarine blue is an inorganic and complex compound formerly obtained from lapis lazuli but now prepared artificially. This famous blue pigment dates back to the early 19th century. Chemically, these are the most complex out of all inorganic class pigments.

Comment: It consists of sodium, aluminum, silicate lattices and polysulphide (-S-S-S) chains. It is produced by heating kaolin, sodium carbonate, sulfur and other inexpensive ingredients together. The blue color of the pigment is due to the S3-radical anion, which contains an unpaired electron. "

Comment: Quoted from here: sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2090536X15000027

Comment: @M.Farooq I posted the first comment, suggesting lapis lazuli, but the OP rejected lapis as too expensive and they want the liquid to be white until it dries, at which point they want a blue tint. So I deleted that comment. Apparently neither Han blue nor Egyptian blue would be acceptable either.

Comment: The OP can check "robin blue" on Amazon pigment which is nothing but dirt cheap from of lapis lazuli. A synthetic and safe pigment.  There is no such paint which is white in solution and bluish when dry.

Comment: @M.Farooq    The only thing I can think of is having a brightener plus a volatile quenching agent in the liquid. Then as the paint dries, the quencher evaporates and the brightener does its brightening. But the list of safe and volatile quenchers is short, e.g., nitromethane is highly toxic.

Comment: @EdV, Don't the brighteners bleach after a while?

Comment: @M.Farooq Yes they do, as far as I know. Then you are stuck with dingy, aka “ecru”. That is why I suggested lapis lazuli in the first place, but it requires dropping the white while liquid condition.

Comment: Yes, the white suspension condition has to be dropped.